# Graphing CPU Usage % on Grafana using influxDB data from Telegraf

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have grafana 3.0.4 / influxdb 0.13.0 / telegraf 0.13.1

I am trying to graph overall CPU usage by %.

When I create a query using the idle time, I get exactly that (I'm looking for 100 - idle time) (usage)

[image: idleusage]

I switched to manual mode and did exactly that:

[image: 100-idletime]

and it works great..

But is there a way to use a math function or something in the normal editor versus dropping into the manual text mode?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some slightly convoluted math using Grafana's Math field setting should do what you want without dropping into manual text mode.

`Math(* -1 + 100)`

[image]